Ruby `resolve-replace` gives net open timeout with ruby 2.6 or below
This issue starts appearing after adding resolv-replace in the environment.
Please see the backtrace, failure is in original_resolv_initialize call in constructor.
2024-05-21 17:54:35 - Net::OpenTimeout - execution expired:
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/resolv-replace.rb:25:in `initialize'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/resolv-replace.rb:25:in `initialize'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:947:in `open'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:947:in `block in connect'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:945:in `connect'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:919:in `start'
    /Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1470:in `request'


Sample code to test with:
require 'net/http'
require 'resolv-replace'
get "/ssrfpasscase" do
   if params[:input] != nil
     url = "http://www."+params[:input]+".com"
     uri = URI.parse("#{url}")
     puts uri.to_s

     http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
     request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

     response = http.request(request)
     #@output=response.to_s

     response.code             # => 301
     response.body             # => The body (HTML, XML, blob, whatever)
     # Headers are lowercased
     response["cache-control"] # => public, max-age=2592000

     # Listing all headers
     @output=""
     response.each_header { |h| do_something(h, response[h]) }
     response.each_header { |h| @output=@output+"#{h.to_s}:#{response[h].to_s}"+"\n" }
   end
   erb :output
 end

